# How can I add a search bar for my website to my website's Google results?

Tags: search

When my website is Googled, I want a search bar for the site to appear in the results, like this:

[image: StackOverflow Google search]

To be clear, I'm referring to the search bar with the placeholder text "Results from stackoverflow.com", right above the "Careers" and "Java" links.

The results for my website have an identical layout, except that there is no search bar.

How can I achieve a search bar in the results?

---

**I'm not sure this can be accomplished through altering my source code, so this question may not even belong on StackOverflow. If that is the case, feel free to migrate the question to whichever SE site in which it belongs.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough rep to put this in a comment, but i would just like to post [this](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.se/2014/09/improved-sitelinks-search-box.html).

Quoting the blog post from google:

> How can I mark up my site?
>
> You need to have a working site-specific search engine for your site. If you already have one, you can let us know by marking up your homepage as a schema.org/WebSite entity with the potentialAction property of the schema.org/SearchAction markup. You can use JSON-LD, microdata, or RDFa to do this; check out the full implementation details on our developer site.
>   If you implement the markup on your site, users will have the ability to jump directly from the sitelinks search box to your site’s search results page. If we don’t find any markup, we’ll show them a Google search results page for the corresponding site: query, as we’ve done until now.
>   As always, if you have questions, feel free to ask in our Webmaster Help forum.